Why don't similar locations of spectral lines produce similar "colors"?
Why don't similar locations of spectral lines produce similar "colors"?
See red arrows below showing different elements but similar locations but different "colors"

Edited image based on the original of the chemistry classes, track "Atomic Theory and Structure" of visionlearning.com, installment Atomic Theory II: Ions, neutrons, isotopes and quantum theory by Adrian Dingle and Anthony Carpi.  (Image ©Neon spectrum: Deo Favente)

Is there any indication that these images are all using the same x-coordinate endpoints and scaling?

Andrew is right. Obviously the Iron spectrum is much broader than the visible spectrum. The blue and violet lines of the Iron spectrum correspond to UV region of the visible spectrum. Also the red lines of the Neon spectrum do not match the red region of the visible spectrum.

I included the link directly to the online site https://www.visionlearning.com/en/  and https://www.visionlearning.com/img/library/large_images/image_6979.png  looks like they forgot to say they adjusted the scale.  Not sure why I was downgraded for this real question.  The site is at fault not me.
They say "We provide high-quality, accessible, educational material in the science, technology, engineering and mathematics (STEM) disciplines at the introductory undergraduate level."

Also, Visionlearning is supported by the The National Science Foundation and the U.S. Department of Education.  Getting down voted because of their mistake..

The source of founding is irrelevant to the question. The link simply does not link to the very chapter, the reference is too broad (like a link "to Wikipedia" in general compared to a specific article e.g., in the English edition).

I don't think "the site is at fault". They didn't "forget" to say they adjusted the scale. The colors of the lines are presumably intended to indicate where in the visible spectrum the lines lie and therefore provide the relative scale to the first image.

@Andrew Thanks to a reverse image search, I identified a plausible address of the image in question.  More so, the authors of said page credit a third party for the spectrum of neon.  So ...

This is more an illustrated comment, than an answer. The question is incompletely addressed; though it links to a source to retrieve the illustration, it does not provide the text (i.e., the very chapter of a lesson) it belongs to to trace how the illustration was obtained.  This is important because though this line spectra are emission spectra, missing energy scale / wavelength aside, the resulting spectra are affected on the charge of the analyte.
There are public databases about these lines, e.g. Line Spectra of the Elements by Reader and Corlis, or the compilation by NIST.  Based on them, it is possible to visualize them.  The demonstration below was compiled with LaTeX usepackage pgf-spectra.*  Except for the last one,** the intensity of the emission lines was equalized; if outside of the visible range, they are depicted in gray.  The scale is in nanometres.  Note the difference passing $\ce{Ne}$ to $\ce{Ne^+}$; or $\ce{Fe}$ over $\ce{Fe+}$, $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ to $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$.

Addition: It was possible to identify a plausible address of the installment where the illustration was used.  Reading the fine print reveals the authors of the page and the author of the spectrum about neon are different.  One can only speculate about the origin of these gray lines; it does not seem there is a consistent start/end and spread of the four spectra along wavelength (e.g., range of blue, red, green lines).
* There already is/was pst-spectra pgf-spectra is based and extends in functionality.
** The extra example about sodium aims to show something potentially useful in hands of spectroscopists here (e.g., teaching).

After installation pgf-spectra, the illustration above was compiled with pdfLaTeX with this MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LSE]{pgf-spectra}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% general setup of the spectra
\pgfspectraStyle[width=\linewidth, axis, begin=150, end=850,axis step=50]

neutral hydrogen:\\
\pgfspectra[element=H]


neon: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Ne]

neon with one positive charge: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Ne,charge=1]


iron: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Fe]

iron with one positive charge: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Fe, charge=1]

iron with two positive charges: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Fe, charge=2]

iron with three positive charges: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Fe, charge=3]


sodium example of a zoom: \\
\pgfspectra[element=Na, charge=0, begin=560, end=600, %
   axis step=5, back=visible25,relative intensity]

\end{document}

For the subsequent upload to the page, the pdf in hand was converted into a png of 300 dpi resolution with inkscape.
